# Joomla K2 item in another item?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-k2

So, I have to work with this Joomla 1.7 installation that the programmer before me didn't treat very well.
It is using K2 plugin, on the home page there is a flash section with 4 tabs and in every tab there is a "More" button that leads to a K2 item.
So, what I want to do is change the item that every "More" button leads to and, naturally, I searched for an .xml file with the hope that it will hold data about the button text and the url.
I found that .xml file, changed the text and URL, no problems with the text change - it reflected on the site immediately, but the buttons still lead to the old K2 items and not to the URLs I specified in the .xml file.
So, my idea now is to load the K2 item that I need in the K2 item that each button leads to. Like, for example, as you would load a video with {rokbox}{/rokbox} .
Anybody has an idea?
And I tried setting up a redirect from Components -> Redirect from the admin menu before I came up with that idea. It didn't work.

Comment: why have you specified the URL in the XML file? Can you also please provide some code, as I;m not sure exactly what you require.

Comment: No relevant code to provide. There is just this flash loaded below the main menu and it takes the url and text for the buttons from an .xml file. But as I come to think of it, I can use a redirection plugin.... Thank you for showing interest in my problem.  :)